# Can't assign multiple values to 3 variables

Tags: json, bash, jq

Request

```
curl -XGET http\://my_host\:9111/api/issues/search\?componentKeys\=my_poject\&facets\=severities\&p\=1\&ps\=1
```

Here response:

```
{
  "total": 10057,
  "p": 1,
  "ps": 1,
  "paging": {
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 1,
    "total": 10057
  },
  "effortTotal": 51031,
  "issues": [
    {
      "key": "AX0NVCNfENszTAxEgX5e",
      "rule": "java:S122",
      "severity": "MINOR",
      "component": "my_project:SomeFile.java",
      "project": "my_project",
      "line": 241,
      "hash": "1111111111",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 241,
        "endLine": 241,
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 46
      },
      "flows": [],
      "status": "OPEN",
      "message": "At most one statement is allowed per line, but 2 statements were found on this line.",
      "effort": "1min",
      "debt": "1min",
      "author": "eugeniur",
      "tags": [
        "convention"
      ],
      "creationDate": "2021-11-11T06:40:05+0200",
      "updateDate": "2021-11-11T06:40:05+0200",
      "type": "CODE_SMELL",
      "scope": "MAIN"
    }
  ],
  "components": [
    {
      "key": "my_project",
      "enabled": true,
      "qualifier": "TRK",
      "name": "Parent",
      "longName": "Parent"
    },
    {
      "key": "my_project:MyFile.java",
      "enabled": true,
      "qualifier": "FIL",
      "name": "XStartDServerComponent.java",
      "longName": "MyFile.java",
      "path": "MyFile.java"
    }
  ],
  "facets": [
    {
      "property": "severities",
      "values": [
        {
          "val": "CRITICAL",
          "count": 5818
        },
        {
          "val": "MAJOR",
          "count": 1459
        },
        {
          "val": "BLOCKER",
          "count": 1286
        },
        {
          "val": "MINOR",
          "count": 1163
        },
        {
          "val": "INFO",
          "count": 331
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to extract keys: `"total", "issues", "facets.values"`.

So I try this in my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly BASE_URL=http://my_host:9111/api
readonly PROJECT_KEY=my_project

read totalIssues facetsArr issuesArr < <(echo $(curl -XGET $BASE_URL/issues/search\?componentKeys\=$PROJECT_KEY\&facets\=severities\&p\=1\&ps\=1 |
                       jq -r '.total, .issues[], .facets[].values'))
echo "total      : $totalIssues"
echo "facetsArr     : $facetsArr"
echo "issuesArr  : $issuesArr"
```

But result is:

```
total      : 10057
facetsArr  : {
issuesArr  : "key": "AX0NVCNfENszTAxEgX5e", "rule": "java:S122", "severity": "MINOR", "component": "MyFile.java", "project": "myProject", "line": 241, "hash": "b68d3b4b390c81e2714d263b31acdd08", "textRange": { "startLine": 241, "endLine": 241, "startOffset": 0, "endOffset": 46 }, "flows": [], "status": "OPEN", "message": "At most one statement is allowed per line, but 2 statements were found on this line.", "effort": "1min", "debt": "1min", "author": "eugeniur", "tags": [ "convention" ], "creationDate": "2021-11-11T06:40:05+0200", "updateDate": "2021-11-11T06:40:05+0200", "type": "CODE_SMELL", "scope": "MAIN" } [ { "val": "CRITICAL", "count": 5818 }, { "val": "MAJOR", "count": 1459 }, { "val": "BLOCKER", "count": 1286 }, { "val": "MINOR", "count": 1163 }, { "val": "INFO", "count": 331 } ]
```

Why "**facetsArr**" get incorrect value?

The "**facetsArr**" must be:

```
facetsArr  : [ { "val": "CRITICAL", "count": 5818 }, { "val": "MAJOR", "count": 1459 }, { "val": "BLOCKER", "count": 1286 }, { "val": "MINOR", "count": 1163 }, { "val": "INFO", "count": 331 } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly inefficient, but it would be much simpler to just parse the (small) response 3 times.

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly BASE_URL=http://my_host:9111/api
readonly PROJECT_KEY=my_project

response=$(curl -XGET "$BASE_URL/issues/search?componentKeys=$PROJECT_KEY&facets=severities&p=1&ps=1")

total=$(jq '.total' <<< "$response")
issues=$(jq '.issues' <<< "$response")
facets=$(jq '.facets[].values' <<< "$response")

# ...
```

Then you don't have to worry about constructing a single output with `jq` that `bash` must parse anyway.

(I've intentionally left the value of `issues` a JSON array, rather than a stream of `issues`, in the event that there is more than a single object in the array.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Use string manipulation to insert a newline (`\n`) between each value, each line will now contain the value you're trying to catch
2. Quote the `jq` command since it may contain spaces <sup>[[info]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067297/5625547)</sup>
3. Set `IFS` to a newline <sup>[[info]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting)</sup>
4. Use `read -d ''` <sup>[[docs]](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html)</sup>

   > `-d delim`
   >
   > continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
   > than newline

---

Applying those fixes, the script will look like:

```sh
IFS=$'\n'
read -r -d '' totalIssues facetsArr issuesArr <<< "$( jq -r '"\(.total)\n\(.facets[].values)\n\(.issues[])"' input)"
echo "total      : $totalIssues"
echo "facetsArr  : $facetsArr"
echo "issuesArr  : $issuesArr"
```

<sup>**Note**: I've replaced the curl command with an actual file called `input` containing OP's JSON</sup>

---

The output will be:

```
total      : 10057
facetsArr  : [{"val":"CRITICAL","count":5818},{"val":"MAJOR","count":1459},{"val":"BLOCKER","count":1286},{"val":"MINOR","count":1163},{"val":"INFO","count":331}]
issuesArr  : {"key":"AX0NVCNfENszTAxEgX5e","rule":"java:S122","severity":"MINOR","component":"my_project:SomeFile.java","project":"my_project","line":241,"hash":"1111111111","textRange":{"startLine":241,"endLine":241,"startOffset":0,"endOffset":46},"flows":[],"status":"OPEN","message":"At most one statement is allowed per line, but 2 statements were found on this line.","effort":"1min","debt":"1min","author":"eugeniur","tags":["convention"],"creationDate":"2021-11-11T06:40:05+0200","updateDate":"2021-11-11T06:40:05+0200","type":"CODE_SMELL","scope":"MAIN"}
```